# Partitioning main partition (sda) into multiple partitions to load another operating system?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am using Linux Mint (not ubuntu but I think the question would apply to ubuntu just as well). While installing Linux Mint (20.3 xfce version), I went with the default partition scheme (I am still in the process of learning about partitioning manually, and also this is one of my first attempts at installing linux on new hardware). I have the following partition scheme so far:

[image]

as you can see there is only one partition. And my main disk is `/dev/nvme0n1` instead of `/dev/sda` (i believe they are equivalent in this case since it is basically my main disk)
What I want to do is eventually end up with a disk (512 GB total size) that has the following structure, basically a *dual boot*:

1. partition for 1 my (current) Linux Mint OS (say 50 GB)
2. partition for an alternate OS (say ubuntu) (say 50 GB)
3. partition  for generic data (remaining: 412 GB)

Is this at all possible from my current setup? Can I partition my current `/dev/nvme0n1` partition into 2 more partitions (2 and 3 from above list) so as to allow me to install another OS? Or should this have been done at the time of installation? Should I redo my installation? (that wont be much of a problem since this a fresh installation) What would be the best course of action, based your experience?

I read [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-create-partition) that you should not partition main disk (sda or in my case nvme0n1) because that

> can make your system unbootable. Only create partitions on secondary disks

(I only have one disk here)

Again, my knowledge is very limited since I am new to partitioning and disk management but I would be very happy to learn. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: you most definitely can partition your main disk. And you already have 2 partitions there. As long as you don't touch the boot partition, you should still be able to boot. At worst, if you mess something up really bad, you can always reinstall.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most definitely can partition your main disk, and you already have 2 partitions there -- a `boot` partition and your main partition. As long as you don't touch the boot partition, you should still be able to boot. At worst, if you mess something up really badly, you can always reinstall.

What you *can't* do is shrink the partition you are *currently booted into*, because that can definitely cause many problems.

You can boot into a live USB and use `gparted` to shrink your main (512 GB) partition down to 50 GB, and create 2 more partitions. Then, when you install a new OS, choose to install it in the second 50GB partition, instead of repartitioning from scratch like you did this time.

Comment: so if I am not mistaking anything... 1) I keep my current (Mint) installation as it is 2) Make a bootable usb for another OS: say ubuntu 3) Boot into this live usb 4) before installing ubuntu in this live environment, open a terminal and type gparted (or any other partioning tool) and shrink the partition down to 50 GB and create another 50 GB partition for ubuntu that Im about to install (rest left for data) 5) install ubuntu? Am I following correctly?

Comment: @FirstUser yes, that is correct. Although you can use your Mint bootable USB to do that now if you would like.

Comment: @FirstUser although you should create a partition for the data manually, as well. That can be done from inside an installed OS if the disk space is "unallocated" though.

Comment: thanks a lot, though Im afraid I have formatted the usb so I'll need to download and burn another ISO again lol. Also when it comes to shrinking the partition, which one should I do: number 5 (from the image above)? Thanks for that note about the data partition: should I format that to ext4?

Comment: you can format to ext4 if it will only be used in Linux; if you plan on accessing it from Windows use NTFS.

Comment: for clarification: the usual advice is to back up all data in the partition that's going to get "shrunk", because while it *shouldn't* cause problems if done properly, you can always make a mistake, and sometimes things go wrong for various reasons, and data can get corrupted. Since you don't have data to lose, you don't have to worry about that, and if it gets ruined you can just reinstall.

Comment: And yes, of course #5 which is a logical partitions inside a container or extended partition (#2). This layout exists because you're using the old MBR ("msdos") partition type. Fine for any Linux as it can be installed in UEFI mode either way but if you intended to dual-boot with Windows then this would be a HUGE problem.

Comment: And you don't need (arguably shouldn't) "create a partition for Ubuntu". Simply shrink the Mint system partition in order to have unallocated space (unallocated space is NOT a partition) that the Ubuntu will use to create at least one partition (default). You can either use the automatic "install alongside option" or select "something else" and then add a partition occupying the unallocated space and also assure the ESP (EFI System Partition - your #1) is selected as "EFI" (it should be select automatically).